# How do I get a range of fragments of the path in svg?

Tags: svg, path

How do I get a range of fragments of the path in svg? As in the figure, a path is created with the pen tool, I can add anchors at any point on the path.

[svg pen tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LItju.png)

Comment: From the image I can tell that the path is made of several Bézier curves: quadratic and cubic. Depending on what you have you may need to change all your commands to uppercase commands and break your path in several paths using the last point of the previous curve as M (move to). To get real help please add your code.

Comment: The picture is taken from a web application. I saw that it has implemented this function, but I don’t know the principle. In the figure, his path is drawn as whole,  is not be splited.

Comment: I would need to see your code in order to understand what you need

Comment: https://app.uxpin.com/edit/8082898#?id_page=108576023，just like this， if path is splited as  several paths， It will become difficult to implement the pen tool function